# React TypeError: teams.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I getting the TypeError: teams.map is not a function while trying to fetch and paint elements from an api. I haven't been able to find the error.

I'm trying to build a simple app with premier league teams and details about them. I'm still writing because stack overflow won't let me publish my question

leagueTeams Component

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function LeagueTeams() {
  const url = 'https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/search_all_teams.php?l=English%20Premier%20League'

  const [teams, setTeams] = useState(null)

  fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => setTeams(data))

  return (
    <div className="teams">
    {teams && teams.map((team, index)=>(
      <div className="team" key={index}>
        <h3>{team.strTeam}</h3>
      </div>)
    

       
    )}</div>
  )
}

export default LeagueTeams
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import LeagueTeams from './components/leagueTeams'

function App() {

  
return(
  <>
  <h1 className="title">Premier League Teams!</h1>
  
  <LeagueTeams />
  </>
)
  }

  
export default App;
```

Comment: Are you sure that `teams` is an array at all(data from 2nd promise)?
And you should set the initial value to `[]` instead of `null`

Comment: You should place the fetch() command in a useEffect hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is `teams.map is not a function`, this is because teams is not actually an array:

```
const url = 'https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/search_all_teams.php?l=English%20Premier%20League'
```

This does not return an array, it returns an object:

```
{"teams":[{"idTeam":"133604","idSoccerXML":"9","idAPIfootball":"42","i....
```

Which means you should update the state via:

```
setTeams(data.teams);
```

Working CodeSandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-jepsen-odc65

Answer (score 1):

as `teams` is going to be array, write state as

```
const [teams, setTeams] = useState([])
```

and write fetch() function in useEffect like this

```
    useEffect(()=>{
 fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => setTeams(data))
},[])
```

this will fetch data when components mounts .

and in map function write it as

```
{teams.length && teams.map((team, index)
```

hope it works

Comment: `.length && ` is obsolete. If the array is empty, the map will also just not return any mapped values.

Comment: @F.P yeah [] is false in javascript and we need not check length